# Multiple Drupal sites in Docker container

Tags: apache, docker, drupal

I started out with a single site but grew that offering. The initial site had a web server and database containers, so as I added sites, I added containers. This included test and prod, so double it! Then I added memcached and SimpleSAMLphp! So 4 containers per site per environment!!!

The host started to act flaky, so I consolidated containers. There are now only 2 database containers (prod and test). There are only 2 memcached and 2 SimpleSAMLphp containers.

I still have one web server container per site.

**My understanding is that, for security purposes, I should create immutable Docker images.** That is easy if each container is a single site.

But if I also consolidate sites into 2 containers (1 for test and 1 for prod), then any changes to one site will require a complete rebuilding of the entire image, which will rebuild all of the sites, whether they changed or not.

This seems risky (other sites might go down unnecessarily), and it will require a more complicated Dockerfile (or accompanying scripts) to pull in all sites into the image.

**So should I try to fix the server flakiness as a result of too many containers, or should I forgo the immutable image and use volumes for each site root?**

Comment: Was the flakiness due to too many containers? A container doesn't really add that much overhead to a process itself. Running 8 processes in a container and 8 containers isn't vastly different, other than how you schedule it all. If you were running thousands of containers, it might start getting hairy.

Comment: I've been told that even a dozen containers is too much if I have multiple MySQL containers, multiple Apache containers, etc. I thought this was because MySQL is better able to manage multiple databases than Docker is able to manage multiple MySQL containers.

Comment: Memory management is always harder when running multiple processes compared to shared hosting as you don't have one big shared pool for everything, you need to configure each instance for it's specific work load to fit within the system. MySQL in particular likes to grab more memory than your average process so needs memory setting changes between dev/test/prod but there's no arbitrary limit to containers just because you have MySQL instances running.

Comment: Production DB's are a bit of an edge case generally with containers... If you do prefer sharing a MySQL instance for all production sites, don't let that change your container design for dev/test and the rest of the components that make up production.

Comment: and make sure your databases have direct access to storage volumes.